# mysql database structure (unique id)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I think most people had serious problems with inserting a value/data into a database (mysql). When I'm inserting a value into a database, I assign an unique id (INT) for that line. When I query the database, easily I can read/modify/delete that line.

With function for() (in php) I easily can read values/data from the database. The problem occurs when I delete a line (in the middle for example).

E.g:

DB:

```
ID | column1 | column2 | ... | columnN
--------------------------------------
1 | abcdefgh | asdasda | ... | asdasdN
2 | asdasddd | asdasda | ... | asdasdN
...
N | asdewfew | asddsad | ... | asddsaN
```

php:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++){
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE ID = '$i' ");
   //Code;
}
```

*$n = last column value from ID

---

Am I need to reorganize the entire database to have a correct "flow" (1, 2, 3, .. n)? Or am I need to UPDATE the each cell?

Comment: your $i variable starting from zero , so firstly executing this command : `SEELCT * FROM db WHERE ID = 0` . CAn you try with this for loop : `for($i=1; $i < $n+1 ; $i++)`

Comment: You should not repeatedly query the database inside a loop if you know the fixed IDs you need to retrieve ahead of time as this creates significant overhead for your script. Instead, query the database once to retrieve all your results and loop over the result set.

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements.

Comment: Don't use [`SELECT *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/) unless you're writing a DB administration program; select only the columns you need.

Comment: @outis: both your comments make sense for only advanced developers. For newbies there is nothing wrong in `SELECT *` and `mysql_*`

Comment: @zerkms: On the contrary, `SELECT *` is a bad habit that will lead to trouble later and the mysql extension is unnecessary. There's no reason to use `mysql_*` and plenty reasons not to. You wouldn't say it's alright for a novice to use bubble sort because they're not advanced enough for quicksort.

Comment: @outis: "that will lead to trouble later" --- in general it is not correct. It could lead to troubles in some specific cases. I've been working with 1TB+ databases (oracle dbms) and hadn't issues with `SELECT *` (in most cases)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reorder a primary key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377628/how-to-reorder-a-primary-key)

Comment: @outis: "You wouldn't say it's alright for a novice to use bubble" - it is good enough as long as you don't have thousands of items to sort and you are not confident enough to implement quicksort. While OP barely has hundred of rows

Comment: @zerkms: I didn't say in every case. It's those some cases that I was referring to. Besides, just because you haven't experienced something doesn't mean it doesn't happen. In any case, comments aren't the place  for debate; if you really want to discuss this, join me in the [MySQL chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing here is unnecessary thanks to [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) in mysql. Run this command from PhpMyAdmin (or another DB management system):

```
ALTER TABLE db MODIFY COLUMN ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Now when insert a row into `db` mysql will assign the ID for you:

```
INSERT INTO db (id, column1, column2) VALUES(NULL, 'abc', 'def');
```

`SELECT * FROM db;`:

```
+--+-------+-------+
|id|column1|column2|
+--+-------+-------+
|1 |old    |oldrow |
+--+-------+-------+
|2 |abc    |def    | <--- Your newly inserted row, with unique ID
+--+-------+-------+
```

If you delete a row, it is true that there will be an inconsistency in the order of the ID's, but this is ok. IDs are not intended to denote the numeric position of a row in a table. They are intended to uniquely identify each row so that you can perform actions on it and reference it from other tables with foreign keys.

---

Also if you need to grab a group of ID's (stored in an array, for example), it is much more efficient to perform one query with an `IN` statement.

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$in = implode(',', $ids);
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM db WHERE id IN ('.$in.')');
```

However, if you want all rows just use:

```
SELECT * FROM dbs;
```

But be weary of [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the rows with query

```
SELECT * FROM db
```

and do whatever you want after

Answer (score 1):

You can *never* ensure, that the ids are continous. As you noticed yourself there are gaps after you delete a row, but even for example when you insert rows within a transaction and don't commit it, because something failed and you need to revert the transaction. An ID is an identifier and not row number.

For example if you want to select X items from somewhere (or such) have a look at `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20;
```

This selects the rows 21 to 30 ordered by their creation time. Note, that I don't use `id` for ordering, but you cannot rely on it (as mentioned).

If you really want to fetch rows by their ID you definitely need to fetch the IDs first. You may also fetch a range of IDs like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

But don't assume, that you will ever receive 4 rows.

Comment: `ORDER BY` goes before `LIMIT`

Comment: I added the `ORDER BY` later, thus it get swapped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ids are [surrogate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)–they are in no way derived from the data in the rest of the columns and their only significance is each row has a unique one. There's no need to change them.

If you need a specific range of rows from the table, use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) to specify them in the query:

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, ..., coln
  FROM `table`
  WHERE id BETWEEN ? AND ?
  ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to reorganize the entire database in order to keep the index. But if you feel like it, you'd have to update each cell.

BTW, look at `mysql_fetch_array()`, it will ease the load on the SQL server.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` has nothing to do with "load"

Comment: 1 query with a fetch_array to treat the data is much lighter than X query. So yes, is this case it has to do with "load"

Comment: it still hasn't. You can use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead with the same "load" reasons lol

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the rows and all columns for that table use:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
```

and then loop through each row with a while statement:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query )) 
{
       echo $row['column_name'];
}
```