# sql database - reset fields to auto increment

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I deleted all rows from the database that had a value of 1, in the no column, from the database (each row either had a 1 in the yes and 0 in the no or 0 in the yes and 1 in the no).  However, now I would like to redo the id column to reflect this change.

For example, I would like the first row(name of DEYRO) to have an id of 1, ELEHC to have an id of 2, AEHSN to have an id of 3, etc all the way until the end of the database(roughly 100 rows but I'm not sure)

Here is an image of what the database looks like:

[image: mysql database screen shot]

Any help would be appreciated, either through phpmyadmin or via an SQL query or something like that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fill in the "holes" in auto-incremenet fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841104/how-to-fill-in-the-holes-in-auto-incremenet-fields)

Comment: I am accessing the fields by incrementing a session which holds a counter.  If there are large gaps in between entries, I will need to refresh the page multiple times before I see the next entry

Comment: Don't use a counter but store in your application the min and max of the ids (that you are currently showing). Then you could a simple: `SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE id > @CurrentMaxID ORDER BY id LIMIT 10` and get the next 10.

Comment: @LoganBesecker Then why not just: `SELECT MIN(id) FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE id > OLD_ID`?

Comment: Thank you very much @BrankoDimitrijevic, that makes things much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to truncate the table and run a script to add the records individually since id field is autoincrement.

hope this helps.

Rhian A.
10-05-2012 NZT